# I cannot run my code in the external terminal in VSCode macOS

Tags: c, macos, visual-studio-code, terminal

I am trying to run my C codes in VSCode on a macOS machine. The only problem is I cannot figure out how to make the code run in the external terminal.

launch. json

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "gcc build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": true,
            "MIMode": "lldb",
            "preLaunchTask": "gcc build active file"
        }
    ]
}
```

tasks.json

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "compile and run C",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "gcc ${file} -o ${fileBasenameNoExtension}  && ./${fileBasenameNoExtension} ",
            "presentation": {
                "reveal": "always",
                "panel": "shared"
            },
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This is also the settings.json file which i tweaked a little bit.

```
{
"window.zoomLevel": 0,
"code-runner.runInTerminal": true,
"C_Cpp.updateChannel": "Insiders",
"terminal.integrated.rendererType": "dom",
"editor.fontSize": 14,
"workbench.tree.indent": 20,
"workbench.tree.renderIndentGuides": "always",
"workbench.editor.highlightModifiedTabs": true,
"terminal.explorerKind": "external",
"terminal.external.osxExec": "Terminal.app"
```

}

Comment: What do you mean by that? What have you tried doing and where is the problem? Did you not manage to compile it? It's really unclear

Comment: I am sorry if I was being unclear. Let me elaborate more specifically.
No matter the code I am running I press CMD+Shift+B to debug and run the code. And it runs on the integrated terminal of VSCode. What I am trying to do is to output the file in the external terminal. I have tried changing "externalConsole: true" as well as some other settings but with an unfortunate result. I am not sure if my launch.json and tasks.json have not been correctly set up or is this a problem with the VSCode application in general.

Comment: Include the contents of "tasks.json" and "launch.json" as part of the question using the [edit] button

Comment: I am new to this so excuse me for my poor formatting skills and lack of elaboration on the topic.

Comment: You should remove the `&& ./${fileBasenameNoExtension}` part from the "command" in "tasks.json" - it launches the built executable after compilation

Comment: Yeah, now it does not run at all...

Comment: Are you actually launching it (with either F5 or the Green Arrow in the debug tab)?

Comment: Actually it works by clicking the green arrow. Which must be the problem because I used to shortcut it by CMD+Shift+B. Might have to check the shortcuts menu to see where I should run the command. Thanks for all the help mate. I appreciate it tons!

Comment: "CMD+Shift+B" is the default shortcut for *building*. The default shortcut for running/debugging the application is "F5": https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_debug

Comment: Ahh I get it. Thanks a lot man. Now I can focus on my work peacefully!

Comment: just create bash file and execute. it works for me better than run command through vscode